# Gems in the groups group, development, test and production were not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to create an article in my table,and when i follow whats in the tutorial,were told to write the command, rails generate migration create_articles, i get this error message . Gems in the groups group, development, test and production were not installed.

below is my gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group  :production do
gem    'pg'
gem    'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Did you run Bundle install?

Answer (score 4):

Since you've installed the gems without development and test environment once, you have to drop the settings by forcibly include test and development, like:

```
$ bundle install --with development test
```

This will clean "without" settings.

Answer (score 0):

To install the gems listed on your Gemfile you need to run the following command in your project folder:

```
bundle install
```

So, after that you can run the rails generators:

```
rails g [model/controller/migration...]
```

Comment: that answer isn't on the question

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that the groups: development, test, and production will install gems listed in those groups respective to their environment.

Meaning, that if a gem is only listed in development, that gem will not install in test or production.